# Adding a new field to the contacts app

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract

I understand that a new contact and additional info regarding the contact can be added into the native contacts app using a contacts intent. But can we create an entirely new field to the contacts app and add info to it from another app? Or by someway manipulate this field, say like having a block of code that adds as a plugin to the contacts app?

For eg: A trouble indicator field for each contact with three possible values 1. Troublesome 2. Not troublesome 3. Friendly. Based on the no. of calls and time period of the calls, the value of the indicator field has to shift automatically.

Assuming i have the logic to do this, how can i make this field a part of the native contacts app? It'd be helpful if you can at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: This would be useful for some other things too like phone numbers for special issues depend from country etc